# phpで検索結果リストからリスト詳細画面を動的に作成したい。

Tags: php

こんにちは。
wordpressのプラグインの中に検索システムをPHPで構築しております。
検索結果の各リストからaタグで詳細画面に遷移する場合に、詳細画面を動的に作成したいと思っており、いろいろと調べたところ、aタグのhrefが以下のようなURLになっているのを見かけます。
例：　http://○○○.com/sample/kensakuDetail/2222
おそらく動的にURLを作成しているようなのですが、どのような仕組みになっているのかがわかりません。
詳細画面は、sqlで取得した結果を表示しているようなのですが、どなたか仕組みが分かる方、ご教示お願いいたします。
上記の内容でなくても、一般的な検索システムの内容でも構いませんので、回答お待ちしております。

Answer (score 0):

まずはじめに、[WordPressのドキュメント・オンラインマニュアル](https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/Main_Page)については熟読されましたでしょうか？
こちらを読んでみて分からない箇所について質問をした方が解決までが早くなると思いますので、
もし、まだ見られていないようでしたら一度ご覧になることをお勧め致します。

さて例のURLですが、URLの形態はWordPress設定内にあるパーマリンクという項目で決まります。
ですので、まずURLに記載されている数字がどのような意味を持つのか、そちらを確認しましょう。
（例に出されているものを見る限り、現状の設定は記事IDかと思われます。ほか、投稿の日時なども設定できます。）

ここまでが前知識ですが、本題として["テンプレート階層"の"概観図"](https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E9%9A%8E%E5%B1%A4)以降をご覧ください。
URLに記載されているページの種別は分かりませんが、"個別投稿記事"だと思われます。
個別投稿は、"single.php"を始めとしたテンプレートのphpで表示の設定されていますので、コチラを編集するといいかと思います。

こちらのPHPを探して編集する前にバックアップし、別テーマとして新規テーマを作成すると間違えた際に直ぐに戻せるので、
作業前にテーマテンプレートの作成方法について一度調べてみると良いかと思います。

また、作業中不明点などあると思いますが、発生した場合は別で新規質問を立てていただければと思います。
がんばってください。